# Alternatives to Destroy() or SetActive()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my script. I'm really looking for a solution without having to post code. ( I'm using Unity 2019 with C#. )

Here's the dilemma:

I have two scripts
1) EnemyDamage
2) EnemySpawn

Both scripts work fine until one of the enemies is killed.

Basically when my enemy('s) die I use Destroy(gameObject) which ultimately is causing the error on my spawn script because the EnemySpawn is still trying to access the destroyed enemy.

The way my spawn script works is multiple enemies can be chosen from a list. Then using coroutines, the enemies appear on screen and then disappear using SetActive(true/false). So even if I elect to set the enemy to false in EnemyDamage, the EnemySpawn will just set it back to true.

So what I need is another way to hide my enemy. ( And I can't just move it out of camera sight because the EnemySpawn will just put it back on a random spawn point in camera view again )

What are some alternatives to Destroy(), SetActive(), or moving out of camera range?

Comment: Use another variable? Set the reference in the spawn script to null? Very hard to say without seeing any code.

Comment: Can't understand your question, There no alternatives to `Destroy` or `SetActive` except Unity creates one.

Comment: So you really want me to post 2,000 lines of code? Really, I am looking for a way to disable the enemy any other possible way besides using enabled,SetActive, or Destroy. Does any alternatives exist? Currently, I disabled the enemies collider, and set its localScale to (0,0,0). This seems to work fine, however, the shoot script attached still activates. So now I'm trying to figure out how to disable the script from only that enemy, not the others.@shingo

Comment: Put it in a list and implement the **OnDisable** method in your **EnemyDamage** to remove it from said list when it dies. Then just check if it is contained in the list in your **EnemySpawn** script before accessing it.

Comment: @AntonioTorro `Destroy` and `SetActive` are enough to remove a GameObject out of the scene, why do you need alternatives? Didn't they work? If not you have found a bug in Unity. But as I know they are in working order, you need fix the problems in your code, such as "why got an error after destroy an object?" or "why the object is actived after set it inactive?". So if you don't post any code but ask for alternatives to `Destroy` or `SetActive`, my answer is no.

Comment: @shingo - Oh, okay, now I know why you're confused. I have 6 enemies on screen I add them into a list and use a foreach to set them all inactive upon start. Then my program grabs 2 random enemies from the list. Then these two enemies react to the spawn code which sets them active/inactive. So when I Destroy an enemy, the code is still trying to access the destroyed enemy and that's where the error comes into play. Which is ultimately why I was seeking alternatives because the way my code is set up, I couldn't use the SetActive() or Destroy().

Comment: @Hristo OnDisable(), I'll look into that! This could be the solution that I need!

Comment: So why not remove the spawned emenies from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this in the the spawn enemy script. It should remove an enemy from the list when that enemy is destroyed .The enemysToRemove variable is there because you cant edit a list while iterating through it (*thanks Hristo*).

```
public List<GameObject> enemys;
List<GameObject> enemysToRemove = new List<GameObject>();

void Update () {
    foreach(GameObject enemy in enemys){
        if (enemy == null) {
            enemysToRemove.Add (enemy);
        }
    }
    foreach (GameObject item in enemysToRemove) {
        enemys.Remove (item);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, put try and catch in-front of everything you do to the enemy`s in the spawn enemy script. Like this:

```
public List<GameObject> enemys;

foreach(GameObject enemy in enemys){
    try{
        //thing I want to do to this enemy
    }catch{
        Debug.Log ("enemy destroyed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice try C.Lang, however **enemys.Remove** this is not possible the way you have written it! Try to execute the code and you will see that it will give an error saying that you can't modify the list while iterating trough it.

Comment: Oops, didn't`t notice that... Thanks for telling me :). I will update my answer